# How to display listview inside a Column?

Tags: flutter-listview

In my Profile Page of App there are 3 Containers. First container displays Profile Picture and Name.
2nd Container having a dropdown button with 3 values (posts, categories and profile).
3rd Container having a Column as a child. This column I want to use listview builder for posts and categories and profile is ready and displaying perfectly. I have used below code inside column children

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
       _selectedItem == "posts" ?
       "I want to use listview builder here" 
       :
       Container(
         height: 0.0,
         child: Text(""),
       ),
       _selectedItem == "categories" ?
       "I want to use listview builder here" 
       :
       Container(
         height: 0.0,
         child: Text(""),
       ),
       _selectedItem == "profile" ?
       "this is working fine and able to see output" 
       :
       Container(
         height: 0.0,
         child: Text(""),
       ),
   ],
  ),
),
```

I searched many examples even on stackoverflow but couldn't any which fits my needs. Profile info, Posts and Categories are fetched from server and stored in var userProfile; List userPosts = new List(); List postCategories = new List(); respectively. I tried many examples to fit as per my need though was not as per my requirement but giving error.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you want to add a list just paste this code there, It will work fine.

```
    ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       //If you get infinite height error use this attribute, it will shrink height of the list to display only available items.
       physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
       //if you want to disable scrolling
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(NamesList[index].name); //Here NamesList is your data list
             },
           )
```